# Zuul proxy to different URL according to logged in user

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm designing some bot farm where each user has its own bot, and I would like to achieve the following

1. User logs in to the web server
2. Zuul server will then extract
   from the DB the IP of the specific user's bot
3. Zuul will act as a
   reverse proxy to the bot, with other users able to do the same thing
   in parallel of course

So far I saw examples to redirect to specific service according to the path. but is it achievable to do this dynamically according to the logged in user's bot IP?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by writing the following filter:

```
  @Override
  public String filterType() {
    return PRE_TYPE;
  }

  @Override
  public int filterOrder() {
    return PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER + 1;
  }

  public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = getCurrentContext();
    ctx.put(REQUEST_URI_KEY, "/test/");
    try {
      if (new Random().nextInt(10) > 5) {
        ctx.setRouteHost(new URL("http://192.168.1.14:8088"));
      } else {
        ctx.setRouteHost(new URL("http://192.168.1.14:8089"));
      }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      log.error("", e);
    }
  return null;
  }
```

my application.properties looks like so:

```
spring.application.name=zuul-server
server.port=8080
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
zuul.routes.test.path=/test/**
```